# d3.js Free hand drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, d3.js

I have an SVG that has various images in it, and it is all hooked up to d3.js's zoom function. Thus when i zoom all the images will zoom accordingly. My next step is to add drawing(hand drawing) functionality to this. When I was creating this prior to using D3.js, i was just using an html canvas and drawing on that. However, it doesnt seem to want to play nicely with d3.js. I am not able to use this same canvas drawing method inside the svg where my other images are. Essentially i want to be able to hand draw so that this 'canvas of hand drawing' will zoom with the images inside the SVG.
1- Does d3.js incorporate any sort of this hand drawing library functionality? Can you point me in the right direction?
2- If not, is there any other way to get point a canvas and the svg to zoom with one another?

EDIT

Heres trying to use d3.js to zoom canvas(the first part is what im using to zoom the SVG's)

///SVG ZOOM

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([.75, 2.0]).on("zoom", zoom);

 d3.select("#mysvg").call(zoom).on('mousedown.zoom',null);


function zoom() {

d3.select("#mapImages").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");

}
```

////Canvas Zoom(not working)

```
 var canvas = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([.75, 2.0]).on("zoom", canvasZoom);

d3.select("#canvasDiv").call(canvas).on('mousedown.zoom',null);

function canvasZoom() {

  d3.select("#mycanvas").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out this d3 example. Play around with how zoom is just using canvas.scale, with d3's event system.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680958

Comment: (Appended, since it's not part of the answer...) 

Your question isn't super clear, but I'll try to be helpful.
Looks like you have SVGs with images inside it.
When you use d3's zoom on the images, it works.
You want to be able to draw on...an HTMLCanvas, but treat it like an image, I think...

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the tips. Still a little unsure...see above for some code that i added to try and make the canvas zoomm, but doesnt work